# How to get properties of Javascript object prototype?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get _firstName and _birthDate from : I tried https://jsfiddle.net/0xLqhufd/

```
var Person = (function () {
function Person(firstName, birthDate) {
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._birthDate = birthDate;
}
return Person;
}());

alert(Object.keys(Person.Prototype));
```

Comment: You've to create new instance of the Class/function

Comment: You aren't currently using the prototype as far as I'm aware. To see the properties of an object you would have to look at the keys of an instance. The protype normally only contains methods or static variables.

Comment: `_firstName` and `_birthDate` aren't properties of `Person.prototype` (and it's `prototype`, lower case, not `Prototype`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get an object's properties before creating a new instance.

```
Object.keys(new Person)
```

Also for your understanding, you have properties with your current instance not in prototype. At this moment your prototype will be empty and it inherits the Object's, The core one, that holds `toString` etc. And those are non enumerable, so you cannot get those by using `Object.keys()`.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0xLqhufd/1/)

Comment: *"At this moment your prototype will be the core one"* No, it won't. It'll be an object with no properties of its own other than `constructor`, which inherits `toString` and such from *its* prototype.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes the Object's prototype. I meant to say that. Let me correct my words there

Answer (score 2):

This is factory function. You need to create instances of the class using `new`.

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person(firstName, birthDate) {
        this._firstName = firstName;
        this._birthDate = birthDate;
    }
    return Person;
}());

var tushar = new Person('Tushar', '15464');
console.log(tushar); // { _firstName: 'Tushar', _birthDate: '15464' }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new person:

```
var newPerson = new Person('Lars', 'Svensson');

console.log(newPerson.firstname);
console.log(newPerson.birthDate);
```

This will allow you to access it's properties.